# can someone tell me whats wrong with this code for a function that gives out qoutes based on mood?

Tags: python

I want to code a function that gives you a motivational quote based on your mood. This is the code I have:

```
import secrets

myLst = ["Cheer up. Although life may not be easy now, in the end it’s all 
worth it. Everything will get better in time. So SMILE!", "the sun will rise 
and we will try again", "No one is in control of your happiness but you; 
therefore, you have the power to change anything about yourself or your life 
that you want to change."]
myLst2 = ["We Generate Fears While We Sit. We Overcome Them By Action", "You 
Are Never Too Old To Set Another Goal Or To Dream A New Dream", "Of course 
motivation is not permanent. But then, neither is bathing; but it is 
something you should do on a regular basis."]
myLst3 = ["Speak when you are angry and you will make the best speech you 
will ever regret", "If you spend your time hoping someone will suffer the 
consequences for what they did to your heart, then you're allowing them to 
hurt you a second time in your mind", "When angry, count four. When very 
angry, swear"]
myLst4 = ["Let us be grateful to people who make us happy", "I have only two 
kinds of days: happy and hysterically happy", "Be happy. It’s one way of 
being wise"]



 def motivationalQuote():    
        userInput = input ("What is your mood? Sad, unmotivated, angry or 
        happy?")
            if sad in userInput
              print(secrets.choice(myLst))
        else:
            if unmotivated in userInput
                print(secrets.choice(myLst2))
            else:
                if angry in userInput
                    print(secrets.choice(myLst3))
                else:
                    print(secrets.choice(myLst4))
```

Can someone help me out? I am an abslute beginner and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: What is it you want fixed?

Comment: What happens currently? What to you expect or want to happen?

Comment: `if sad in userInput`. Is `sad` declared somewhere else?

Comment: When I try to use the code I get a syntax error in the if sad in userInput line

Comment: You are missing several colons. Use an editor/IDE with syntax highlighting, such as PyCharm's community edition.

Comment: i basically want it to check if the word sad was given as an input idk if thats the way to do it

Comment: `sad` is a Python variable named `sad` with unknown value where `'sad'` or `"sad"` is a string whose content is the 3 letters `sad`. You are confusing the two. And your `if` syntax is wrong.

Comment: You are using `sad`, et al, like they are variables. To use as a string put quotes around them. https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

```
import random
sad = ["Cheer up. Although life may not be easy now, in the end it’s all 
worth it. Everything will get better in time. So SMILE!", "the sun will rise 
and we will try again", "No one is in control of your happiness but you; 
therefore, you have the power to change anything about yourself or your life 
that you want to change."]
unmotivated = ["We Generate Fears While We Sit. We Overcome Them By Action", "You 
Are Never Too Old To Set Another Goal Or To Dream A New Dream", "Of course 
motivation is not permanent. But then, neither is bathing; but it is 
something you should do on a regular basis."]
angry = ["Speak when you are angry and you will make the best speech you 
will ever regret", "If you spend your time hoping someone will suffer the 
consequences for what they did to your heart, then you're allowing them to 
hurt you a second time in your mind", "When angry, count four. When very 
angry, swear"]
happy = ["Let us be grateful to people who make us happy", "I have only two 
kinds of days: happy and hysterically happy", "Be happy. It’s one way of 
being wise"]

mood = input("What is your mood? Sad, unmotivated, angry or happy? ")

def motivational_quote(mood):
    if 'sad' in mood:
        print(random.choice(sad))
    elif 'unmotivated' in mood:
        print(random.choice(unmotivated))
    elif 'angry' in mood:
        print(random.choice(angry))
    else:
        print(random.choice(happy))
motivational_quote(mood)
```

### Changes overview

You didn't need to use the layers of if/else; just use an `elif` statement. You forgot colons in some spots to introduce the new logic block and you also didn't put the strings you were searching for in quotation marks. Some of your variable/function names were camelCase, so I changed them to underscore_case as per PEP8. Instead of creating a function with no inputs, it seemed to me more clear to define a variable called mood and define that as a parameter for the function, then call the function below. Your lists were named unclearly so I changed their names.

There are more efficient ways to do this, but I kept your structure as I thought it might be more clear to you.

Answer (score 6):

To be more Pythonic, I would put the quotes in a dictionary:

```
import random

sad_quotes = [
    "Cheer up. Although life may not be easy now, in the end it’s all worth it. Everything will get better in time. So SMILE!",
    "the sun will rise and we will try again",
    "No one is in control of your happiness but you; therefore, you have the power to change anything about yourself or your life that you want to change.",
]
unmotivated_quotes = [
    "We Generate Fears While We Sit. We Overcome Them By Action",
    "You Are Never Too Old To Set Another Goal Or To Dream A New Dream",
    "Of course motivation is not permanent. But then, neither is bathing; but it is something you should do on a regular basis.",
]
angry_quotes = [
    "Speak when you are angry and you will make the best speech you will ever regret",
    "If you spend your time hoping someone will suffer the consequences for what they did to your heart, then you're allowing them to hurt you a second time in your mind",
    "When angry, count four. When very angry, swear",
]
happy_quotes = [
    "Let us be grateful to people who make us happy",
    "I have only two kinds of days: happy and hysterically happy",
    "Be happy. It’s one way of being wise",
]

quotes = {
    'sad': sad_quotes,
    'unmotivated': unmotivated_quotes,
    'angry': angry_quotes,
    'happy': happy_quotes,
}


def motivationalQuote():
    user_mood = input("What is your mood? Sad, unmotivated, angry or happy?")
    if user_mood in quotes:
        quote = random.choice(quotes[user_mood])
        print(quote)
    else:
        print('I have no quotes for a ' + user_mood + ' mood.')
```

Answer (score 1):

Several things:

- `if` statements require a `:` at the end of them
- `sad`, `unmotivated`, etc. are interpreted as variables. I'm assuming you meant `if 'sad' in userInput`
- This wasn't actually breaking your code, but will clean it up - instead of nesting more `if` statements inside an `else`, use `elif`
- Improvement - your code currently assumes that any answers not including `"sad"`, `"unmotivated"`, or `"angry"` must be happy. Why not handle `"happy"` explicitly and add an extra case that let's the user know you don't understand?

  ```
  import secrets
  myLst = ["Cheer up. Although life may not be easy now, in the end it’s all worth it. Everything will get better in time. So SMILE!", "the sun will rise and we will try again", "No one is in control of your happiness but you; therefore, you have the power to change anything about yourself or your life that you want to change."]
  myLst2 = ["We Generate Fears While We Sit. We Overcome Them By Action", "You Are Never Too Old To Set Another Goal Or To Dream A New Dream", "Of course motivation is not permanent. But then, neither is bathing; but it is something you should do on a regular basis."]
  myLst3 = ["Speak when you are angry and you will make the best speech you will ever regret", "If you spend your time hoping someone will suffer the consequences for what they did to your heart, then you're allowing them to hurt you a second time in your mind", "When angry, count four. When very angry, swear"]
  myLst4 = ["Let us be grateful to people who make us happy", "I have only two kinds of days: happy and hysterically happy", "Be happy. It’s one way of being wise"]


  def motivationalQuote():    
          userInput = input ("What is your mood? Sad, unmotivated, angry or happy?")
          if 'sad' in userInput:
                print(secrets.choice(myLst))
          elif 'unmotivated' in userInput:
                print(secrets.choice(myLst2))
          elif 'angry' in userInput:
                print(secrets.choice(myLst3))
          elif 'happy' in userInput
                print(secrets.choice(myLst4))
          else:
                print('I cannot tell how you are feeling!')
  ```